# Obtaining a list of Wagtail posts to display in a Django template outside of Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a main Django website, which consists of a main page at `/` using standard django templates, and then a wagtail blog situated at `/blog`

On my homepage, I would like someone to be able to show the most recent published articles from the wagtail blog.

I'm having a lot of trouble doing this as I can't find any resources or guides.

So far I added a model for my homepage (which didn't have one previously), just to obtain blogs:

```
from myblog.models import BlogPage


class HomePage(Page):
    def blogs(self):
        blogs = BlogPage.objects.all()
        blogs = blogs.order_by('-date')
        return blogs
```

Then for my homepage template I have:

```
{% for blog in page.blogs %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a class="blog-post-link" href="{% pageurl blog %}">
      <h3>{{ blog.title }}</h3>
    </a>
    <div class="blog-intro">
      {{ blog.body|richtext|truncatewords_html:50 }}
      <a class="read-more" href="{% pageurl blog %}">Read More &raquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

However nothing is displayed, nor are any errors given.

How can I obtain and display a list of published Wagtail posts in an app outside of Wagtail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your homepage is handled by a standard Django view and URL route, then defining a `HomePage` model will not change that by itself - to go down that path you would also need to:

- update your URL routes so that the root path is handled by Wagtail, not just the `/blog/` path (i.e. remove the existing route for your homepage view and change `path("blog/", include(wagtail_urls))` to `path("", include(wagtail_urls))`)
- create an instance of the HomePage within the Wagtail admin
- Adjust the site setup under Settings -> Sites so that the default site points to that homepage as its root page, rather than your blog index page

However, none of this is necessary if you just want to add some Wagtail-derived data to your existing homepage setup - you can just add the `BlogPage` query to the data that your view function passes to the template. Assuming the view function currently looks something like:

```
def home(request):
    # ... do some processing here ...
    return render(request, "home/homepage.html", {
        'foo': 'bar',
    })
```

this would become:

```
def home(request):
    # ... do some processing here ...

    blogs = BlogPage.objects.all()
    blogs = blogs.order_by('-date')

    return render(request, "home/homepage.html", {
        'foo': 'bar',
        'blogs': blogs,
    })
```

You can then access the variable `blogs` in your template - e.g. `{% for blog in blogs %}`.

Comment: Ah thank you! I think I just tried too early, I should have known it would be via the view and that making a model does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a list of Wagtail posts to display in a Django template outside of Wagtail, you can use the

> wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Page.objects.live()

method. This will return a QuerySet of live pages that you can use to retrieve the posts you need. For example, to get a list of blog posts from the blog page:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

blog_page = Page.objects.get(slug='blog')
blog_posts = Page.objects.live().descendant_of(blog_page)
```

You can then use the QuerySet to access the individual posts and their properties. For example, to get the title of each post:

```
for post in blog_posts:
    print(post.title)
```

You can also add additional filters to the QuerySet to obtain more specific results, such as only retrieving posts in a certain category or from a certain author.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Wagtail but did you import wagtail tags in your template?

Comment: I did, no errors on that front.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for contributing to StackOverflow!
You've used an answer to ask the original poster for details. Better to use a comment under his question for that: answer should preferably be used only for solutions to the questioner's problems, so that future viewers find solutions much more quickly.